# sed, seperating a variable (providing a number) from instruction for insertion of text at a specific line

Tags: text-processing, sed

I'm having some trouble with sed and seeing a variable providing a number instruction for an insertion of text at a specific line.

here is the working code without the variable:

```
sed -i '1i\NewLineHere\' ~/file/location/here.txt
```

I need to change the number 1 to $var, but with the letter 'i' remaining next to it (no space), while not being seen as part of the variable. I use " " instead of ' ' so that sed can see the variables correctly, I have tried countless different attempts and none have worked. An example of what the problem looks like without any attempt to disconnect the 'i' from the variable while keeping it next to it:

```
 sed -i "$vari\NewLineHere\" ~/file/location/here.txt
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where `{}` quoting of variable names is useful.  In your case, `${var}`

For example:

```
$ var=100
$ echo $vari

$ echo ${var}i
100i
```

The `{...}` act as a "scoping" for the variable name.

(Side note: be careful with the `\` character when switching between `'` and `"`).

Comment: brilliant, that nicely separates the variable name, but your warning is also true, as i am experiencing problems with \ while using " how can I avoid this problem?

Comment: You have to quote them with an additional backslash: `echo '\'` vs `echo "\\"`